# Angular-chart.js click on bar and change it's background color

Tags: angularjs, colors, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using angular-chart.js to paint a simple bar chart, when I click the bar ,how to change background color?

```
 $scope.click = function (points, evt) {
    // console.log(points,evt);
};
```

Comment: background of what ? bar ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan change bar background colo

Comment: Do you know how to redraw chart ,when I click the bar? ths @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 1):

You can do this onClick

```
 onClick: (point, elements) => {
      if (elements && elements.length) {
        var segment = elements[0];
        segment._model.backgroundColor = "#f6954d"

        $scope.colors[segment._index] = "#f6954d";
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ncoTtvqeUFtPdoSgzmB6?p=preview)**

Comment: very nice ,but I want click another bar ,others bar recovery before background color!  @Sajeetharan

Comment: Why answer is removed

Answer (score 0):

For the people working with legacy code like myself... 
I have an answer to this.

With angular-chart.js, use the `chart-dataset-override` property. With this, you can set the `borderColor` to accept an array, representing each data index.

```
<canvas id="myBarChart" 
               class="chart chart-bar"
               chart-colors="colors"
               chart-data="data" 
               chart-labels="labels"
               chart-series="series"
               chart-options="options"
               chart-click="onClick"
               chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" // <--- what you want
</canvas>
```

This is how I defined mine:

```
 $scope.datasetOverride =  [
                            {
                             borderWidth: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // defaults to no border
                             borderColor: "rgb(225, 225, 225)", // white
                            }
                            // can add more objects here for other datasets
                           ];
```

Grab a reference to your chart from an 'on-create' event like so:

```
$scope.$on('chart-create', function (evt, chart) {
            $scope.chart = chart;
        });
```

Then use a conditional in your click event function to set the increase the border, using the event index.
If so, I changed all 4 of these properties.

```
element[0]._model.borderWidth = 10;
element[0]._chart.config.data.datasets.borderWidth[barIndex] = 10;
element[0]._view.borderWidth = 10;
$scope.datasetOverride[0].borderWidth[element[0]._index] = 10; // something like this
```

Then reference that chart and call the `update` trigger at the end of your click function.

`$scope.chart.update();`

Magic. Grabbing on to the update method will create a smoother change in your graph than `$scope.$apply()`

Hope this helps someone! 
Cheers.